# Stop event bubbling with .on in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have stripped the following back to the bare bones, I am passing more attributes around to call specfic information in my ajax.

```
$(document).on("click", ".call", function(){
    $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "showform.asp",dataType:"html",data: {},cache: false,success:function(result){
        $("#LoadArea").html(result);
}});
});


$(document).on("click", ".cbcall", function(){
    $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "select.asp",dataType:"html",data: {},cache: false,success:function(result){
        $("#LoadArea").html(result);
}});
});
```

Above is an example of the Jquery I am using and below is the html I am using.

```
<p class="call">click here to load</p>
<div id="LoadArea"></div>
```

When the **click here to load** is clicked the showform.asp page content is loaded into the LoadArea div. The content of the showform.asp is as follows

```
<div class="call">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbcall">
</div>
```

The issue is that if I click on the checkbox(.cbcall) the event bubbles up and the showform.asp gets loaded. I am fairly new to Jquery so I would like to know how to stop event bubbling but still be able to check and uncheck the checkbox that is loaded in showform.asp.

I have tried return false; but this will not check the checkbox.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE** - Tweaked code to match suggestion

I have updated my starting page to match Nicola's code (thanx Nicola)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".call").on("click", function(e){
        //check that event is originated by a <p class="call"> element
        if($(e.target).is('.call')){
        alert('.call actioned');
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "showform.asp",dataType:"html",data: {},cache: false,success:function(result){$("#LoadArea").html(result);}});
        }
});


$( ".call").on("click", ".cbcall",  function(e){
        alert('radio actioned');
    //Stop immediate propagation
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "select.asp",dataType:"html",data: {},cache: false,success:function(result){$("#LoadArea").html(result);}});
});
});

<p class="call">click here to load</p>
<div id="LoadArea"></div>
<!-- additonal code below here -->
<div class="call">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbcall">
</div>
```

In addition I have added the contents of the showform.asp to the bottom of the page and added some alerts to the Jquery.

When I click on either the `<p class="call">click here to load</p>` or the `<input type="checkbox" class="cbcall">` on the initial page functions work, the alerts fires and the ajax loads but when I use just the `<p class="call">click here to load</p>` and try the same calls from the ajax loaded showform.asp page nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are capturing the event at the document level and so it has already bubbled up!

EDIT - Since the second element is dynamically added you should do

```
$(".call").on("click", function(e){
    //check that event is originated by a <p class="call"> element
    if($(e.target).is('p.call')){
      $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "showform.asp",dataType:"html",data: {},cache: false,success:function(result){
        $("#LoadArea").html(result);
      }});
     }
});


$( ".call").on("click", ".cbcall",  function(e){
     //Stop immediate propagation
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "select.asp",dataType:"html",data: {},cache: false,success:function(result){
        $("#LoadArea").html(result);
}});
```

Comment: +1, although I would assume the `on()` calls in the OP were setup that way as the `.cbcall` and `.call` elements are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for everybodies help so far but although I do not want the .cbcall to bubble up to the .call within the showform.asp I still need the .call within the showform.asp to action. The site I am building uses the .call on the initial load and in various ajax calls - sorry for not being clear

Comment: @decker27 i left only the code which leaves both event handler, i just use event.target to avoid triggering unwanted ajax call

Answer (score 2):

As you've bound the event to the `document` you *can't* prevent the click from bubbling back to the document (it's already bubbled there before the event-handler fires, otherwise the event-handler wouldn't fire).

To minimise the amount of bubbling, bind the event-handler to the closest parent-element of the `.cbcall` element that exists in the DOM at the time the events are assigned. That way the event will bubble *only* to that element (provided you call `event.stopPropagation()`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue within the following code:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $('a.ajaxlink').on('click tap', function(e) {
    // function
    }
}
```

To prevent the click event bubbling on click after window resize I simply added off() before the on('click tap') :

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $('a.ajaxlink').off().on('click tap', function(e) {
    // function
    }
}
```